# Creating custom surrogate key in pig

Tags: apache-pig, uniqueidentifier, surrogate-key

Is there any way to create a custom surrogate key in Pig?.

Ex: we have data like below

```
Salary City Name

20000 newyork john   
30000 sydney joseph   
60000 delhi mike   
30000 sydney joseph
```

And for this data we need to create the surrogate key as below and result should be as below.

```
     Salary City Name

SCN1 20000 newyork john    
SCN2 30000 sydney joseph   
SCN3 60000 delhi mike  
SCN2 30000 sydney joseph
```

Instead of creating Random unique key?

Thanks in Advance!!.

Answer (score 1):

Distinct the data first,use RANK and CONCAT to get the custom key for each distinct row.Then join distinct with original dataset.Finally generate the required columns.

```
A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage('\t');
B = DISTINCT A;
C = RANK B;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE CONCAT('SCN',$0),$1,$2,$3;
E = JOIN A BY ($0,$1,$2),D BY ($1,$2,$3);
F = FOREACH E GENERATE E::$3,E::$0,E::$1,E::$2;
DUMP F;
```

This is how it works with the sample data

**A**

```
20000 newyork john   
30000 sydney joseph   
60000 delhi mike   
30000 sydney joseph
```

**B**

```
20000 newyork john   
30000 sydney joseph   
60000 delhi mike
```

**C**

```
1 20000 newyork john   
2 30000 sydney joseph   
3 60000 delhi mike
```

**D**

```
SCN1 20000 newyork john   
SCN2 30000 sydney joseph   
SCN3 60000 delhi mike
```

**E**

```
20000 newyork john SCN1 20000 newyork john     
30000 sydney joseph SCN2 30000 sydney joseph   
60000 delhi mike SCN3 60000 delhi mike 
30000 sydney joseph SCN2 30000 sydney joseph
```

**F**

```
SCN1 20000 newyork john    
SCN2 30000 sydney joseph   
SCN3 60000 delhi mike  
SCN2 30000 sydney joseph
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Inquistive Mind for helping me in generating the unique surrogate key.Here is the pig script which I have tested and worked well.

```
 A = LOAD '/user/root5/data3.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
 B = DISTINCT A;
 C = RANK B;
 D = FOREACH C GENERATE CONCAT('SCN',$0),$1,$2,$3;
 E = JOIN A BY ($0,$1,$2),D BY ($1,$2,$3);
 F = FOREACH E GENERATE $3, $0, $1, $2;
 DUMP F;
```

### And the outputs for each step is as below:

```
DUMP A;
(20000,newyork,john)
(30000,sydney,joseph)
(60000,delhi,mike)
(20000,newyork,john)
(30000,sydney,mike)
(60000,delhi,mike)  

DUMP B;
(20000,newyork,john)
(30000,sydney,mike)
(30000,sydney,joseph)
(60000,delhi,mike)

DUMP C;
(1,20000,newyork,john)
(2,30000,sydney,mike)
(3,30000,sydney,joseph)
(4,60000,delhi,mike)

DUMP D;
(SCN1,20000,newyork,john)
(SCN2,30000,sydney,mike)
(SCN3,30000,sydney,joseph)
(SCN4,60000,delhi,mike)

DUMP E;
(20000,newyork,john,SCN1,20000,newyork,john)
(20000,newyork,john,SCN1,20000,newyork,john)
(30000,sydney,mike,SCN2,30000,sydney,mike)
(30000,sydney,joseph,SCN3,30000,sydney,joseph)
(60000,delhi,mike,SCN4,60000,delhi,mike)
(60000,delhi,mike,SCN4,60000,delhi,mike)

DUMP F;
(SCN1,20000,newyork,john)
(SCN1,20000,newyork,john)
(SCN2,30000,sydney,mike)
(SCN3,30000,sydney,joseph)
(SCN4,60000,delhi,mike)
(SCN4,60000,delhi,mike)'
```